# Google Tag Manager (GTM) not working on SharePoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, google-api, sharepoint-2013, google-tag-manager

I added the GTM code inside the SharePoint Master Page inside the body tag.

```
<body>
<--Body content goes here -->

<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
        <noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXXXX"
        height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
        <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
        new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
        '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
        })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-T9XLSX');</script>
        <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

</body>
```

But It seems that the script is not properly fired as the whole content is wrapped by a form element as following.It generate by SharePoint.

```
<body>
    <form method="post" action="" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm">
    <--Body content goes here -->

    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
            <noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXXXX"
            height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
            <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
            new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
            '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
            })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-T9XLSX');</script>
            <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
   </form>
</body>
```

Is there a way we can properly place the tag in SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one workaround. You can directly **edit** the 
'**.master**' page in SharePoint 2013 **using** **sharepoint designer** and
insert the the **GTM** just **after the closing tag** of sharepoint form as below,

```
</SharePoint:SharePointForm>
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXXXX"
    height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','sss');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Comment: This code is disappear when we do any update in masterpage. Can anyone please suggest a solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it for a SharePoint Online site collection. Assuming that the Publishing Features are turned on, I:

1. Put all the Google Tag Manager stuff into a dedicated HTML file.
2. Upload the HTML file somewhere like the root Site Assets library.
3. Go to the Design Manager > Snippet Tool
4. Configure a Content Editor Web Part to render the HTML file.
5. Embed the Content Editor Web Part into your master page with no chrome/make invisible with your preferred method of choice or use the native **ms-hide** class
6. Check-in, publish.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a sandbox solution for this in codeplex. I guarantee this works fine. all installation guidance is there.

Comment: Can you please post the link ?